# Enumerated list with different indents customisations and different

Tags: enumerate, itemize, moderncv

I am writing my resumé using LaTeX and the image below is where I am currently. The code is also typed.

```
   \section{\underline{\textbf{EDUCATION}}}
     \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 2, Location 2 }}\\
        Programme Read 2 \hspace\fill Month2 Year2. 
        \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 1, Location 1 }}\\
        Programme Read 1 \hspace\fill Month1 Year1.
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item \textbf{Research Projects}
        \end{enumerate}
     \end{itemize}
```

The help I need is that, I prefer the **Research Projects** not to be given a number. However, it should be indented by 10mm (length for a tab). The lists of Projects will then be written under **Research Projects** with the same indent level as its header and also not given numbers or any form of listing. Let me also add that, I have globally set my bulleting (from `\itemize`) to go to the farthest left using `\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}`. If I can be guided on how to use the `CV`, `moderncv`  class and also helped with templates, that will also be great.

New code that works is given below:

```
\section{\underline{\textbf{EDUCATION}}}
 \begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 2, Location 2 }}\\
    Programme Read 2 \hspace\fill Month2 Year2. 
    \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 1, Location 1 }}\\
    Programme Read 1 \hspace\fill Month1 Year1.
    \begin{enumerate}[label={}] \itemsep -1.5pt
    \item \textbf{Projects}
    \item \textit{Project Title 1}
    \item \textit{Project Title 2}      
    \end{enumerate}
 \end{itemize}
```

[image: Current State... Needs working on].

The new outlook is also given in the second image.[image]

Comment: Check out the enumitem package,

Comment: Hello John, I used the enumitem package to get here. For now, I am searching for answers on how to make the customisations I am requesting for. If you can help, I definitely will be glad.

Comment: If you don’t want the number of the enumerate environment, which does exactly that, have you thought about using a ‘tabbing’ environment instead?

Comment: Hello @MarkusG.. I am hearing of the tabbing environment for the first time. I'll try and look it up on google.

Comment: I’m not surprised. It is a bit old fashioned, but in some cases it does have advantages over tables, including the lack of added vertical space above and below.

Comment: Hello @MarkusG. I have added new code to include to include the solution to what I was looking for. Kindly have a look and give inputs if any. Information from you on the tab environment will also be great - Knowledge should never be despised. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

As per request, here some code using the `tabbing` environment. As I mentioned it is apparently not used that often by people on this site and is quite reminiscent of using a typwriter. The advantage (in my opinion) is that it does not add any spaces around it, like `tabular` or `itemize` would, giving you more control.

The first line defines the positions of your tabs: `\hspace*{10mm} \= \kill`
This defines the first tab to be `10mm` from the left margin and `\kill` makes sure the line is not output.

Any subsequent line may look like this:  `some text (or empty) \> more text \\`. Note that if the initial text is longer than the space provided, there will be no linebreak and the text will just go on above the other text.

In my code below, I also added a version of you code using the macros provided by the `moderncv` documentclass (which you are using according to the tag of the question). This will alter the output quite a bit, but it is already optimised for use in a CV-type document.

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\moderncvstyle{casual}

\firstname{FN}
\familyname{FN}
\address{}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    \section{\textsc{Education}}
    \cventry{mm/yy}{Programme 4}{University 4}{Location 4}{}{Description 4}
    \cventry{mm/yy}{Programme 3}{University 3}{Location 3}{}{   
        \begin{tabbing}
            \hspace*{10mm} \= \kill
            \> \textbf{Projects}\\
            \> \textit{Project Title 1} \\
            \> \textit{Project Title 2} \\
        \end{tabbing}}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 2, Location 2 }}\\
        Programme Read 2 \hspace\fill Month2 Year2. 
        \item \textbf{\textit{Name of University 1, Location 1 }}\\
        Programme Read 1 \hspace\fill Month1 Year1.
        \begin{tabbing}
            \hspace*{10mm} \= \kill
            \> \textbf{Projects}\\
            \> \textit{Project Title 1} \\
            \> \textit{Project Title 2} \\
        \end{tabbing}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

On an unrelated note, I suggest you not use all-caps and underline (both individually or worse both at the same time) this isn't the middle ages. If you want capital letters, better use `\textsc{}`.

Comment: Comment very well appreciated.